# Estimate correlation in non-normally distributed (e.g. Poisson), unbalanced, repeated measures data

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures, nonparametric, poisson-distribution

I have a large behavioural data set, and I would like to measure pairwise correlations between several of my outcome variables, and binned categories of outcome variables. However, I have multiple 'subjects' (animal nests), with highly variable numbers of fixed observation periods between each (from 2-30+). What is the best method to test correlation, that properly models the distribution (typically Poisson or negative binomial) and the mixed design?

I have found the Rmcorr R package, but its solution to normal data is to bootstraping. Is there a rank-based method? Should I reshape my data and use a glmm with my outcome variables as predictor and predicted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an unexpectedly challenging issue. Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2012) provides a method for some non-linear distributions with implimentation in R using the lmer4 package: http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x

The method is to calculate the ratio of variance in a model with fixed effects (a fitted model), to the variance components of each random effect (additive or otherwise depending on distribution).

Comment: Here is some further comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/calculating-r2-in-mixed-models-using-nakagawa-schielzeths-2013-r2glmm-me

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with that, but I think the *intraclass correlation coefficient* is what are you looking for. 
Honestly, I cannot elaborate more on this, but you can start from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) to have an overview and moving towards more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thank you, that is much appreciated, and closely related to my question.